# My own external js codes work once in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Please Some Help!

My project has 4 page that one of them is About.
I use react-router for change path and contents between this pages with their link

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import "./js/script";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Portfolio from "./components/Portfolio";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <div id="main-container-ma2web">
          <nav id="main-menu-ma2web">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to='/' className="menu-link-ma2web">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to='/portfolio' className="menu-link-ma2web">Portfolio</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to='/about' className="menu-link-ma2web">About</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to='/contact' className="menu-link-ma2web">Contact</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

          <Switch>
            <Route path='/about'>
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/contact'>
              <Contact />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/portfolio'>
              <Portfolio />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/'>
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

In About component I use some JavaScript code for some objects in it.

I attach my external JavaScript codes to project with different way such as script tag in `index.html`, functions, import, `componentDidMount` an so on...

If I be in About page `http://localhost:3000/about` and reload the page my JavaScript code works well but if I change path and return to About, JavaScript code does not works!

what should I do?

About.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = 'About MA2WEB - Full-Stack Web Developer';
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="main-section about animate">
                <article className="about-contents-ma2web">
                    <h1 className="typing-ma2web">I have experience in <span
                    className="txt-rotate"
                    data-period="2000"
                    data-rotate='[ "JavaScript", "Reactjs", "Nodejs", "GSAP", "PHP", "MySQL", "Wordpress", "SEO" ]'>
                        </span>
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        I can develop both client and server side languages.
                    </p>
                </article>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

script.js

```
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Some information about what errors you facing, console logs, using any node server that render the html etc ?. "Code not works" is so vague to answer.

Comment: @nithin "code not works" means my javascript codes (text typing function that write in script.js) not work. it works just once - if i reload About page.

and when I go to Home page and return to About page my Function in External js file does'n work

Comment: add your about.js component code

Comment: @KishanJaiswal I added

Comment: do the changes as @japsz said

Comment: add exact to every path

Comment: @MA2WEB How are you including script.js and what is the content in script.js. One possible reason could be, the About component is unmounted when navigated to a different route. And when you navigate back to about section, since you are using external script, it might not be aware of the changes happened to dom through react. Like event listeners might get lost, and many any other changes that I might not be aware of. So you may try to reinitialize the script on component did mount

Comment: @nithin I know your mean.... but can't solve it.... I imported script.js in (index.js, about.js) and also try to call it as function in componentDidMount and also attached it to index.html... all of ways work same. just once working if I be in about path in browser.....

Comment: @MA2WEB Can you post a sample code of script.js.

Comment: @MA2WEB a sample of how are you importing the scripts would also be useful

Comment: @Japsz I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your script on window.onload, which runs only once (First page load).

To get around this behaviour, you should call the function manually on componentDidMount.

**Approach 1**

In your script.js you can assign the main function to the window object like below

```
window.RotateText = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("txt-rotate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-rotate");
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
};
```

And in your About.js change componentDidMount to something like below.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "About MA2WEB - Full-Stack Web Developer";
    if(window && window.RotateText){
        window.RotateText();
    }
  }
```

Complete code.

**script.js**

```
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = "";
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + "</span>";

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === "") {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.RotateText = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("txt-rotate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-rotate");
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
};

window.onload = window.RotateText;
```

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default class About extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "About MA2WEB - Full-Stack Web Developer";
    if(window && window.RotateText){
        window.RotateText();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main-section about animate">
        <article className="about-contents-ma2web">
          <h1 className="typing-ma2web">
            I have experience in{" "}
            <span
              className="txt-rotate"
              data-period="2000"
              data-rotate='[ "JavaScript", "Reactjs", "Nodejs", "GSAP", "PHP", "MySQL", "Wordpress", "SEO" ]'
            ></span>
          </h1>
          <p>I can develop both client and server side languages.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

**Approach 2.**

Export default function from script.js.

```
export default function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("txt-rotate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-rotate");
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
}
```

Import the function in any component you need.

```
import rotateText from "../js/script";
```

Call the function in componentDidMount.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "About MA2WEB - Full-Stack Web Developer";
    if(window){
        rotateText();
    }
  }
```

Complete code

**script.js**

```
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = "";
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + "</span>";

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === "") {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

export default function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("txt-rotate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-rotate");
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
}
```

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";
import rotateText from "../js/script";

export default class About extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "About MA2WEB - Full-Stack Web Developer";
    if(window){
        rotateText();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main-section about animate">
        <article className="about-contents-ma2web">
          <h1 className="typing-ma2web">
            I have experience in{" "}
            <span
              className="txt-rotate"
              data-period="2000"
              data-rotate='[ "JavaScript", "Reactjs", "Nodejs", "GSAP", "PHP", "MySQL", "Wordpress", "SEO" ]'
            ></span>
          </h1>
          <p>I can develop both client and server side languages.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as right answer / upvote if you found it helpful. Good day :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try importing your external js file in the **"index.js"** file.

Comment: First, change to BrowserRouter instead of Router and secondly try including exact to your path and also try checking the console for some error logs.

Comment: How can i test it? in cmd? what should i write?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router`.

You can rename the import by using `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router'`

Comment: I import this alredy

Comment: i noticed since you edited your post with more code. Therefore i don't see nothing wrong with react-router as it is written.

Comment: ¿Are you using any different kind of serving your react app instead of `react-scripts start`? I've had this exact problem when trying to serve the html build using `nginx` as a reverse proxy

Comment: I'm beginner in React... really 50% know what did you say :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because `react-router` loads `index.html` once. Any redirecting after that only repaints the DOM and doesn't rerun any code in `script` tags. The only way to rerun `script` tags is to reload the page (which you've figured out).

One suggestion is append the script tag whenever your component mounts. Don't forget to cleanup after yourself.

```
export default class About extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = 'About MA2WEB - Full-Stack Web Developer';

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = "myScript";
    script.text = "alert('hello')";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const script = document.getElementById("myScript");
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main-section about animate">
        <article className="about-contents-ma2web">
          <h1 className="typing-ma2web">I have experience in
            <span className="txt-rotate"
              data-period="2000"
              data-rotate='[ "JavaScript", "Reactjs", "Nodejs", "GSAP", "PHP", "MySQL", "Wordpress", "SEO" ]'>
            </span>
          </h1>
          <p>
            I can develop both client and server side languages.
          </p>
        </article>
      </section>
    );

  }
}
```

I've attached a sample using `alert('hello')`. I would recommend getting the `alert('hello')` popup to appear as desired **first** and then debug from there. Everyones setup is different so this solution might need to be slightly tweaked. However, the principles should be the same.